# Laravel Nova App\Model not found after resource created

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova, laravel-migrations

I created a Building Model and resource, which I did by the following.

`php artisan make:model Building -m`

`php artisan nova:resource Building`

created my migrations, and works fine, but I also need Building Types so I created the following.

`php artisan make:model BuidlingType -m`

`php artisan nova:resource BuildingType`

But when I want to access the dashboard I get an error:

````
Class 'App\BuildingType' not found (View: /Users/Username/projects/enest/vendor/laravel/nova/resources/views/layout.blade.php)```
````

Comment: you have a typo : `php artisan make:model BuidlingType -m`, you wrote `BuidlingType` it should be `BuildingType`

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can correct the model in the resource:

```
/**
 * The model the resource corresponds to.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public static $model = 'App\BuidlingType';
```

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/#defining-resources